# Android: How to get latest data for each holder of RecyclerView using ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am figuring out how to get image url from the API for each holder whenever I scroll to that position. I'm thinking about getting the image url from a ViewModel but I don't think a RecyclerView adapter works with a ViewModel.

Adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {

    // Get imageId using the position. dataset is the set of imageId's.
    val imageId = dataset[position]

    // How to call the API to get an image
    // My idea below; not real code
    val imgUrl = ImageViewModel.getImgUrl(imageId)

    // Set image using Coil
    holder.imageView.load(imgUrl)
}
```

My idea for the ViewModel:

```
class ImageViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val imageLinks = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

    fun getImgUrl(imageId: String){
        val imgUrl = imageLinks.getOrDefault(imageId, null)
        if (imgUrl != null) { return imgUrl }
        
        else {
             // 1. Call the API
             // 2. Update imageLinks
             // 3. Return the imgUrl using callback(??) or other methods                      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a ViewModel doesn't work with a RecyclerView? You could just pass an instance of the ViewModel in to your adapter at construction and call it like you have described. Or you could give the adapter a list of URLs directly instead of IDs. If you are getting the URL from a callback or API you won't be able to "return" it directly there from the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

If my uderstanding of your question is right (You have a list of image ids submitted to your recylcer view and as you scroll past each image you want to call an API with the respective `image_id` as the query param retrieving the `image_url` through it.)

If that's what you want to build then why don't you just retrieve the first 10 or 20 `image_url` via their `image_id` and then use pagination to load the next set of images.